# Send data to server and store in SQL Server using sockets

Tags: c#, sql-server, sockets, asynchronous

I am trying to use socket programming for receiving some information from client side (for example: disk usage or something like that).

I am using async method for multiple clients and tried to write to SQL Server but I didn't store whole information to SQL Server. Communication stream over byte array between client and server but how can I store this byte array to SQL Server during the communication?

---

Sorry for the late response guys,

Here is the code. There are 2 projects. one of them is server and the other one is client. there are 2 classes in server project.

Classes;

```
class Listener
{
    private Socket _socket;

    public bool Listening { get; private set; }
    public int Port { get; private set; }

    public Listener(int port)
    {
        Port = port;
        _socket=new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (Listening)
        {
            return;
        }

        _socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(0,Port));
        _socket.Listen(0);
        _socket.BeginAccept(callback, null);
        Listening = true;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (!Listening)
        {
            return;
        }

        _socket.Close();
        _socket.Dispose();
        _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    void callback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket socket = this._socket.EndAccept(ar);

            if (SocketAccepted!=null)
            {
                SocketAccepted(socket);
            }
            this._socket.BeginAccept(callback, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public delegate void SocketAcceptedHandler(Socket e);

    public event SocketAcceptedHandler SocketAccepted;
}


class Client
{
    public string ID { get; private set; }
    public IPEndPoint EndPoint { get; private set; }

    private Socket sck;

    public Client(Socket accepted)
    {
        sck = accepted;
        ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        EndPoint = (IPEndPoint)sck.RemoteEndPoint;
        sck.BeginReceive(new byte[] {0}, 0, 0, 0, callback, null);
    }

    void callback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            sck.EndReceive(ar);

            byte[] buf=new byte[8192];
            int rec = sck.Receive(buf, buf.Length, 0);

            if (rec<buf.Length)
            {
                Array.Resize<byte>(ref buf, rec);
            }
            if (Received!=null)
            {
                Received(this, buf);
            }

            sck.BeginReceive(new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 0, 0, callback, null);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            sck.Close();

            if (Disconnected!=null)
            {
                Disconnected(this);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public void Close()
    {
        sck.Close();
        sck.Dispose();
    }
    public delegate void ClientReceivedHandler(Client sender, byte[] data);
    public delegate void ClientDiscconnectedHandler(Client sender);

    public event ClientReceivedHandler Received;
    public event ClientDiscconnectedHandler Disconnected;
}
```

Server project Main Form:

[Server Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBcyZ.png)

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    private static Listener _listener;

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _listener = new Listener(8);
        _listener.SocketAccepted += new Listener.SocketAcceptedHandler(_listenerSocketAccepted);
        _listener.Start();

    }

    private void _listenerSocketAccepted(Socket e)
    {
        Client client = new Client(e);
        client.Received += new Client.ClientReceivedHandler(client_Received);
        client.Disconnected += new Client.ClientDiscconnectedHandler(client_Disconnected);


        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            ListViewItem i=new ListViewItem();
            i.Text = client.EndPoint.ToString();
            i.SubItems.Add(client.ID);
            i.SubItems.Add("XXX");
            i.SubItems.Add("XXX");
            i.Tag = client;
            listViewClients.Items.Add(i);

            //textBox1.Text = "New Connection : " + e.RemoteEndPoint + "    Time : " + DateTime.Now;
        });
    }

    private void client_Disconnected(Client sender)
    {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listViewClients.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                Client client=listViewClients.Items[i].Tag as Client;

                if (client.ID==sender.ID)
                {
                    listViewClients.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void client_Received(Client sender, byte[] data)
    {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listViewClients.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                Client client = listViewClients.Items[i].Tag as Client;

                if (client.ID == sender.ID)
                {
                    listViewClients.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
                    listViewClients.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Client Side Main Form:

[Client Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQNRK.png)

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sck.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8);
        MessageBox.Show("Connected");
    }

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int s = sck.Send(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(txtMsg.Text));

        if (s>0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Message Sent..");
        }
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sck.Close();
        sck.Dispose();
        Close();
    }

    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //lis
    }
}
```

I have 2 questions.

1- How can I insert a data to sql came from client?

2- the listview item flickers and does not go away, when I close my client app with btnClose.

Comment: TCP sockets have maximum datagrams sizes of approximately 1500 bytes.  Larger messages are broken into multiple datagrams.  So to store data into database the byte array from client must contain blocks so you can break the data into smaller pieces.  For example if you were receiving from client 100 Banking Accounts,  at the end of each Bank Account would have a break character.  Then the server could store each bank Account one at a time to the SQL Server.  Or you could just send one Bank Account at a time so the client didn't have to break the 100 Bank Accounts into individual accounts.

Comment: Okan, please add code example. It is not clear right now how you do this and what actually do you want.